# Prompt em javascript não redireciona

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento, prompt

Tenho o seguinte script em uma página:

```
<script>
    function fnPage(){
        var page = prompt("Para quel página deseja ir?");
        if (page != null) {
            location.href="http://" + page;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Quando preencho com o endereço de O popup aparece normalmente com espaço para preencher com um endereço, mas o redirecionamento não funciona quando clico em OK. Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

Comment: Tente `window.location.href`

Comment: @LeonKlaj muitos atributos da `window` podem ser acessados sem chamar a `window` de fato.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function fnPage(){
        var page = prompt("Para qual página deseja ir?");
        if  (page!= null) {//so corrigir aqui nessa linha page dentro do parenteses
            location.href="http://" + page;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas foi um erro na hora de postar aqui. No código está da forma correta: (page != null)

Answer (score 0):

Corrija o seguinte trecho: `if page (!= null)`  mudando para `if (page!= null)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script>
        function fnPage()
        {
            var page = prompt("Para que página deseja ir?","http://");

            if (page!= null) 
            {
                if(page.indexOf("http://") == -1){ page = 'http://' + page; }
                location.href = page;
            }
        }
    </script>   

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Mudar página" onclick="fnPage()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse erro eu cometi na hora de postar aqui. No script está da forma correta, e não funciona. Já corrigi a postagem.

Comment: Mas aqui o código funcionou. Testei esse código que colei aí embaixo no Firefox, no Chrome e no IE11(precisei clicar em um botão para permitir execução de scripts na página), qual navegador vc está usando?

Comment: Acrescentei agora um fragmento de código que verifica se http foi digitado e se não tiver sido, acrescenta na url.

Comment: Estou usando Opera. Mas eu tenho outros scripts similares em outras páginas q estão funcionando normalmente, com redirecionamento a partir de popups.

Comment: Testou esse código da minha resposta no Ópera e não funcionou?

Comment: Não tinha prestado atenção na alteração q vc fez. Agora funcionou perfeitamente. Valew!

Answer (score 0):

Mais um detalhe que acho interessante acrescentar. Se eu adiciono à pagina:

```
<p id="test"> </p>
```

E mudo o script para:

```
function fnPage(){
    var page = prompt("Para qual página deseja ir?");
        if (page != null) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = page;
            location.href="http://"+ page;
        }
 }
```

O endereço aparece na página (no parágrafo id="test"), mas só pisca rapidamente, não se mantém na página. Não sei se isso ajuda.

Comment: É porque em seguida location.href muda a página.

Comment: Eu eliminei a linha do redirecionamento, e ainda assim o endereço só pisca na tela.